# MYSQL drop table when all the values within a specific column are equal to "DONE"

Tags: mysql, database, raspberry-pi

I am programming MYSQL and I use Python on Raspberry PI 4.

I need to drop table when all the values in my status_s column are equal to "DONE". I cannot figure out how to drop table under a certain condition. MYSQL tables can be found here for testing:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/siZmmKWLjRDdpYX6deEPYF/1

Initially, the status_s values are not "DONE". As my program runs, the values update and eventually all of them will be "DONE", at that point, I do not want to have this table anymore as it is not important.
Thanks in advance

****UPDATE**** Adding snippet of Python program

```
def update_data_when_complete(conn,table_name):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) = SUM(Status = 'DONE') FROM {table}"
    cur.execute(sql.format(table=table_name))
    complete_result = cur.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    #print("COmplete result = ",complete_result[0])
    # if complete_result[0] is 1 here, all rows are "DONE" and must delete table after few minutes
    if(complete_result[0] == 1):
        sql = "DROP TABLE {table}"
        cur.execute(sql.format(table=table_name))
        conn.commit()
    else:
        print("Table not fully complete yet")
```

Comment: DDL in client code is bad practice (except operations with temporary tables). Maybe truncating the table is enough?

Comment: Does your program run in such a way that it uses one database connection for the entire lifetime of that table or does the table exist _before_ the program runs and _after_ if not all are DONE? If it is the full lifetime, you could probably use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...` and it will be eliminated when no longer in use by the connection.

Comment: This is just a temporary table. I am generating a table and then once the operation is fully completed, I want to get rid of it. In my application, multiple computers use single mysql DB and need to be able to access the same information this is the only purpose I have created mysql DB - so multiple computers can access data easily and fast. After this operation is done, I delete this table, and do the same thing with a new table.

Comment: *This is just a temporary table.* Temporary table is visible only in the connection where it was created in. So none "multiple computers" may use it.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for the confusion. A temporary table I meant that I just create it, use it shortly and then never want to see it again. I didint actually mean MYSQL TEMPORARY. As I mentioned, I just use it so I can share information between 2 machines.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Create event procedure:

```sql
CREATE EVENT remove_temptable
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
COMMENT 'Remove `temptable` when its `status_s` column is equal to "DONE" in all rows.'
DO
BEGIN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
            FROM INFORMATOIN_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'temptable' ) THEN
    IF !( SELECT SUM(status_s != 'DONE')
          FROM my_database.temptable ) THEN
        DROP TABLE my_database.temptable;
    END iF;
END IF;
END;
```

This procedure will check the table `temptable` for its existence firstly. If it exists then the procedure checks does a row with non-NULL value in `status_s` column other than `'DONE'` exists. If not then the procedure drops the table.

The procedure is executed each minute. You may adjust how often it is executed. Also, when it is created, you may enable or disable it using ALTER EVENT (for example you may enable it after temptable creation and disable after you ensure the table is dropped).

Do not forget to enable Event Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats good but I do not think this is best suited for my application, since the table name is a unique serial code which is saved as a variable in my python program. After the operation is complete, I loose the name of this table and just overwrite the variable with a new table name. In my python, I have a function complete_operation() which is being executed last. When this function is called, it is very high chance all the rows will be "DONE" so I can just drop the table, but there are times, when the some of the rows are not "DONE" even when operation is complete

Comment: That is why I must do an extra check before I delete the table.

Comment: Unless I would be able to call the event in my complete_operation function. At that point, I still know the table name, but I assume if I call the function once, I do not need to have the table name saved since the event is already called?

Comment: @LukasPetrikas *the table name is a unique serial code which is saved as a variable in my python program.* This is solvable. You may store the name in some service table (does some table with aoolication settings exists? use it...) in `complete_operation()`, retrieve it in the procedure and use dynamic SQL for dropping it. *Unless I would be able to call the event in my complete_operation function* Event procedure is executed by the server, this does not depend on an application.

Comment: Alternatively you may create event procedure with definite table name from your `complete_operation()` function dropping previous event procedure.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether all the rows are "DONE" for the table that we are currently are working on? I think this way would be most convenient for me. Everytime complete_operation() is called, I would check if I need to drop the table or not.

Comment: I think I came up with a good solution. At the end of operation in my complete_operation() function, I can execute few querries: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/siZmmKWLjRDdpYX6deEPYF/5.   First of all, I check the total amount of rows, and then check how many of those rows are "DONE". If both are equal, that means all of them are "DONE" and I drop table, else do not drop.

Comment: *First of all, I check the total amount of rows, and then check how many of those rows are "DONE". If both are equal, that means all of them are "DONE" and I drop table, else do not drop.* One query `SELECT COUNT(*) = SUM(Status_S = 'DONE') FROM table1` is enough. It will return either `1` (all rows are "DONE") or `0` (not all).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for! I was not really aware of this type of query. So you can use "=" in sql query and if both sides are equal will return 1, else 0?. Thanks a lot

Comment: @LukasPetrikas Compare operator `=` compares and returns either TRUE or FALSE or UNKNOWN. In the output list these values are replaced with their aliases `1`, `0` and `NULL` respectively.

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: Hello. I have implemented a method that you suggested and everything works fine and as expected, however, new issue appeared. I have noticed a problem where the same operation is started by accident, and since the table is deleted, there is no way for me to know whether it has already been completed or not. This might happen very very rarely but it will and I want to avoid it. The only way for me to avoid it, is to delay the SQL query for example drop table after 2 minutes. Is that possible to achieve? I am slightly concerned about mysql sleep query.

Comment: If I use mysql sleep query, will I be able to use mysql with other queries as normal? Or I must wait for 2 minutes before executing any other query?

Comment: @LukasPetrikas Maybe simply increase schediling period - till 3 minute, for example? SLEEP is not applicable - you must avoid concurresnt event procedures execution...

Comment: At the moment, my query runs without any scheduler, i just simply use your suggested query and that works. I am currently learning more about the scheduler, and this seems like that should work: ```CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS]delete_table
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTES
DO
DROP TABLE table1``` Since I already do the checking beforehand, and only if the "done" counter matches the number of rows this query will be executed, otherwise will not be executed

Comment: @LukasPetrikas Such event procedure is wrong because of: 1) it drops the table unconditionally 2) it does not check does the table to drop exists. Events are used to perform periodical and/or scheduled code, and they are not used for immediate code.

Comment: Please check the code snippet that I have added to my original question. I do not need to do a condition check in this query since I am doing it before. If it passes the if statement from the condition before, I know for certain that this table exists and needs droping after a few minutes. All I need is in my code to replace ``` DROP TABLE {table} ``` query with a query that would delay droping by few minutes.  Would creating a simple event as I have shown in my previous comment would not be sufficient?

Comment: I just want to generate a one time event that would delete this table after 3 minutes. When I need to delete a new table, I would create a new one time event with a different table name. That was my idea.

Comment: @LukasPetrikas This makes sense. Set this event to auto-delete in this case.